# Vertically align SVG to center of available space

Tags: css, svg, tailwind-css

I have a Tailwind card that displays an SVG icon to the left on large screens and on top on medium size screen and smaller.

I can align the icon along the x-axis. However, on the y-axis I can't get it right.

I used some padding classes, which do the job a bit. Since I can move the icon away from the top, but this also add extra space between the icon and the text underneath.

Is there an obvious way the center the icon in de middle/center along both the x- and y-axes of the available space?

You can have a look at the snippet to see how far I got till now.

```html
<link href="https://www.windesheim.nl/assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.9.6/tailwind.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.9.6/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!--start card image-->
                <div class="max-w-md mx-auto bg-white shadow-md overflow-hidden md:max-w-2xl mt-6 mb-6">
                    <div class="md:flex">
                        <div class="md:flex-shrink-0">
                            <span class="icon fill-current inline-block text-brand-1-darker icon--lightbulb h-48 mx-auto drop-shadow3 w-full object-cover md:h-full md:w-48"><svg width="50%" height="50%"
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 352 512" aria-hidden="true"
                                    focusable="false">
                                    <path
                                        d="M96.06 454.35c.01 6.29 1.87 12.45 5.36 17.69l17.09 25.69a31.99 31.99 0 0026.64 14.28h61.71a31.99 31.99 0 0026.64-14.28l17.09-25.69a31.989 31.989 0 005.36-17.69l.04-38.35H96.01l.05 38.35zM0 176c0 44.37 16.45 84.85 43.56 115.78 16.52 18.85 42.36 58.23 52.21 91.45.04.26.07.52.11.78h160.24c.04-.26.07-.51.11-.78 9.85-33.22 35.69-72.6 52.21-91.45C335.55 260.85 352 220.37 352 176 352 78.61 272.91-.3 175.45 0 73.44.31 0 82.97 0 176zm176-80c-44.11 0-80 35.89-80 80 0 8.84-7.16 16-16 16s-16-7.16-16-16c0-61.76 50.24-112 112-112 8.84 0 16 7.16 16 16s-7.16 16-16 16z">
                                    </path>
                                </svg></span>
           
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-8">
                            <div class="uppercase tracking-wide text-sm text-indigo-500 font-semibold">Title</div>
                            <p class="block mt-1 text-lg leading-tight font-medium text-black">Lead</p>
                            <p class="mt-2 text-gray-500">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--end card image-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `span` wrapping the SVG to be flex, and then use `items-center`.

```html
<link href="https://www.windesheim.nl/assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.9.6/tailwind.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.9.6/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!--start card image-->
<div class="mx-auto mt-6 mb-6 max-w-md overflow-hidden bg-white shadow-md md:max-w-2xl">
  <div class="md:flex">
    <div class="md:flex-shrink-0">
      <span class="icon text-brand-1-darker icon--lightbulb drop-shadow3 mx-auto flex h-48 w-full items-center fill-current object-cover md:h-full md:w-48"
        ><svg class="" width="50%" height="50%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 352 512" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false">
          <path d="M96.06 454.35c.01 6.29 1.87 12.45 5.36 17.69l17.09 25.69a31.99 31.99 0 0026.64 14.28h61.71a31.99 31.99 0 0026.64-14.28l17.09-25.69a31.989 31.989 0 005.36-17.69l.04-38.35H96.01l.05 38.35zM0 176c0 44.37 16.45 84.85 43.56 115.78 16.52 18.85 42.36 58.23 52.21 91.45.04.26.07.52.11.78h160.24c.04-.26.07-.51.11-.78 9.85-33.22 35.69-72.6 52.21-91.45C335.55 260.85 352 220.37 352 176 352 78.61 272.91-.3 175.45 0 73.44.31 0 82.97 0 176zm176-80c-44.11 0-80 35.89-80 80 0 8.84-7.16 16-16 16s-16-7.16-16-16c0-61.76 50.24-112 112-112 8.84 0 16 7.16 16 16s-7.16 16-16 16z"></path></svg
      ></span>
    </div>
    <div class="p-8">
      <div class="text-sm font-semibold uppercase tracking-wide text-indigo-500">Title</div>
      <p class="mt-1 block text-lg font-medium leading-tight text-black">Lead</p>
      <p class="mt-2 text-gray-500">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--end card image-->
```